# Implement Iterator and DoubleEndedIterator for a simple struct

Tags: rust

How should I modify the following code so that `c.iter().rev()` can work as expected or is there a better solution to Implement Iterator and DoubleEndedIterator for `MyCollection`? I know I can use `MyCollection .0.iter()` directly, but in the real code, there are some problems because I need to do some extra calculations.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyCollection(Vec<i32>);

impl MyCollection {
    fn new() -> MyCollection {
        MyCollection(Vec::new())
    }

    fn add(&mut self, elem: i32) {
        self.0.push(elem);
    }

    fn iter(&self) -> MyCollectionIterator { //canot return self.0.iter() in real codes
        MyCollectionIterator {
            data: self,
            index: 0, //shoud be data.0.len() for rev iter.
        }
    }
}

pub struct MyCollectionIterator<'a> {
    data: &'a MyCollection,
    index: usize,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for MyCollectionIterator<'a> {
    type Item = &'a i32;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let ret = if self.index < self.data.0.len(){
            Some(&self.data.0[self.index])
        }else {
            None
        };
        self.index += 1;
        ret
    }
}

impl<'a> DoubleEndedIterator for MyCollectionIterator<'a> {
    fn next_back(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let ret = if self.index > 0 {
            Some(&self.data.0[self.index - 1])
        }else {
            None
        };
        self.index -= 1;
        ret
    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut c = MyCollection::new();
    c.add(0);
    c.add(-1);
    c.add(2);
    c.add(-3);
    c.add(4);
    c.add(-5);

    for n in c.iter(){ //work correctly
        println!("{n}");
    }

    for n in c.iter().rev(){ //no output, because MyCollectionIterator.index is 0.
        println!("{n}");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're implementing `DoubleEndedIterator` wrong because you only have a single position. You'd need to add a `back_index` or something like that

Comment: Iterators that implement `DoubleEndedIterator` need to be able to take items from both ends independently. So taking from one end shouldn't affect the other end (aside from possibly making it reach the end sooner)

Comment: I would have a `fn iter(&self) -> impl DoubleEndedIterator<Item = i32>` method that just returns the iterator from `self.0.iter()`: no need to re-invent the wheel when you're just using a `Vec`